# Single Email-Validator showing result after refreshing but i have to show my result in the same page

Tags: html, json, python-3.x

`<form target="_blank" action="{{ url_for('handle_email') }}" method="post"`

```
 id="email">
    <div class="splash">
        <input type="text" class="input-box" id="email" placeholder="enter email here" name="email">
        <p class="splash-subhead">
        Email spider can find thousand of emails in seconds.
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="pure-button" id="search-btn" value="Get Started">
        </p>
```

THIS IS MY PYTHON CODE.

```
@app.route('/email', methods=['POST'])
def handle_email():
    email = request.form['email']
    url = "http://spiderapi.herokuapp.com/api/emails/"
    print("requesting: ", url)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url, json={"email": email, "key": "C88B933A691E16C56EBC92BCC9A7E"}, headers=headers)
    print(r.json())
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return jsonify(r.json()), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({"response": " Something when wrong ", "status_code": 400});
```

This is a simple email-validator code and I want to return the result of my email whether it is valid or invalid on the same HTML page. Now it is refreshing the page and showing the result.